# How to iterate to create variables in a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Suppose I have the following code:

```
classifiers_name_all = [('AdaBoostClassifier', AdaBoostClassifier(), 'AdaBoost'),
                        ('BernoulliNB', BernoulliNB(), 'Bernoulli Naive Bayes'),
                        ('DummyClassifier', DummyClassifier(), 'Dummy Classifier')]

clf_values = []
for clf_na in classifiers_name_all:
    clf_values.append((locals()['score_'+clf_na[0]+'_mean'], locals()['score_'+clf_na[0]+'_stddev']))
clf_values
```

The code above doesn't quite work.

I want to get a list which contains the variables:

```
clf_values = [(score_AdaBoostClassifier_mean, score_AdaBoostClassifier_stddev),
              (score_BernoulliNB_mean, score_BernoulliNB_stddev)        
              (score_DummyClassifier_mean, score_DummyClassifier_stddev)]
```

How do I do this? Many thanks.

Comment: What is the resultant value of  clf_values.?? Have you cross checked if locals() contains the variables u are looking for.?

Comment: Use a list or a dictionary instead of generating variable names.

Comment: Hi @Akash Sundaresh, how do you cross check this?

Comment: Hi @Klaus D., with this example that I have, how do you do this?

Comment: You did not show us how the variables got into the local namespace, but that is the place where they should go into a dictionary instead.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work".. Does it throw error?? Does it execute fine but does not yeild the result you are expecting???

Comment: From whatever you have given us, it is likely to either throw KeyError or execute fine but clf_values contains a list of nones..

Comment: Thanks @Akash Sundaresh. When it returns a list of Nones, does it mean the code works but I just haven’t assigned the variables like you had earlier mentioned? Also, do you know if `locals()` be used on the right hand side of the equal sign `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From whatever info you have given so far, I infer that there are no key errors and the resultant list is a list containing nones.

This can only mean, that your code works fine but the variables u are trying to access have 'None' values assigned to them. Check why your values are having None values and once that is fixed, this list will get desired values.

Comment: Hi @Akash Sundaresh, yes you are right. The code works. I just needed to first declare the variable at the top otherwise the code will populate the code with None's. Many thanks again for your help, given you an upvote!